# Studying the probability of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $W:=(W_1,W_2,W_3,...,W_k)$ be a random vector of dimension $k \times 1$ taking values $(1,0,0,..,0)$, $(0,1,0,...,0)$,$(0,0,...,1)$. Assume that $W$ has a discrete uniform distribution.

Let $1\{.\}$ be an indicator function taking value $1$ if the condition inside is satisfied and $0$ otherwise.

Let $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$ be some real scalars $\geq 0$.

Let $\mathcal{G}:=\{j \in \{1,...,k\} \text{ s.t. } r_j >0 \}$, i.e. $\mathcal{G}$ is the set of the subscripts of the strictly positive numbers among $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$.

Let $|\mathcal{G}|$ denote the cardinality of $\mathcal{G}$.

Let $\gamma>0$.

How does the probability of
$$
\{ \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}} r_j * 1\{W_j=1\}>\gamma\}
$$
vary with $|\mathcal{G}|$ if we fix $\gamma$ and $r_1+r_2+...+r_k$?

Comment: You posted this question earlier. It's still confusing. You appear to be using the scalars as component indices, coefficients, AND in a constraint. Is there a way to separate the notation so you can refer to a vector component $W_i$ without using the scalars $A..Z$?

Comment: Its also not clear what we are using the $q$ and $\epsilon$ for. Why not just make $W$ a categorical RV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution, then you can do away with the indicator function and simply use the dot product of $\mathcal{N}$ with $W$.

Comment: I have tried to ingobate your first comment. Thank you!

Comment: My idea is that: if the cardinality of G grows and the sum of integers is fixed, then the sum on the rhs of the inquality above is expected to decrease. But I'm not quite sure and I don't know how to formalize it

Comment: Ok, this is getting clearer. What are we doing with the $q$ ans $\epsilon$. Could we simply set $q=0,\epsilon=1$ and come up with the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets re-cast a few concepts to clarify the issues:

Based on your description, only $1$ component of $W$ can be non-zero. Therefore, 
$$\overrightarrow{W}\in \{0,1\}^k:\sum_{i=1}^k W_i = 1$$

$$r_i\geq 0 \implies \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}} r_j * 1\{W_j=1\}=\overrightarrow{r}\cdot\overrightarrow{W}$$

Now, we are assuming:

$$\sum r_i=R>0$$

You are asking about the following probability:

$$G:=P(\overrightarrow{r}\cdot\overrightarrow{W} > \gamma|R,\gamma>0)$$

Specifically, you want to know:

Does the probability depend on $N:=|\mathcal{G}|$ (defined in your post) if we know the values of $\gamma$ and $K$?

**Case 1**: $\gamma \geq R \implies G=0$

**Case 2**: $\frac{\gamma}{N}<\frac{R}{N}\leq\gamma$

Now,  $N\leq k$ by definition, and we know that there exists *some* combination(s) of the $r_i$ whose sum exceed $\gamma$. Case 2 implies that not *all* the coefficients can be greater than $\gamma$.

Without knowing the specific values of $r_i$, the vector of $r_i$ could fall into any one of the three following categories:

1. *All* $r_i \in \mathcal{G}$ are required to exceed $\gamma \implies G=0$
2. *Subsets* of $r_i \in \mathcal{G}$ are required to exceed $\gamma\implies G=0$
3. Up to $\min\left(\lfloor \frac{R}{\gamma}\rfloor,N\right)$ of the $r_i \in \mathcal{G}$ are individually greater than $\gamma\implies G\leq \frac{\min\left(\lfloor \frac{R}{\gamma}\rfloor,N\right)}{k}$

**Case 3**: $R>N\gamma$:

Here, we know we no longer need *all*  $r_i \in \mathcal{G}$, but we also can allow every single  $r_i \in \mathcal{G}$ to be greater than $\gamma$, and we know that *at least* $1$ of the coefficients is greater than $\gamma$.

Therefore $\frac{1}{k}\leq G \leq\frac{N}{k}$

So, the probability $G$ is *partly* controlled by $N$.