# Studying the probability of an event with a continuous distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $W:=(W_1,W_2,W_3,...,W_k)$ be a random vector of dimension $k \times 1$ where each $W_j$ has a continuous uniform distribution in $[a,b]$, $0<a<b$.

Let $1\{.\}$ be an indicator function taking value $1$ if the condition inside is satisfied and $0$ otherwise.

Let $d_1,d_2,...,d_k$ be some real scalars $\in [a,b]$.

Let $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$ be some real scalars $\geq 0$.

Let $\mathcal{G}:=\{j \in \{1,...,k\} \text{ s.t. } r_j >0 \}$, i.e. $\mathcal{G}$ is the set of the subscripts of the strictly positive numbers among $r_1,r_2,...,r_k$.

Let $|\mathcal{G}|$ denote the cardinality of $\mathcal{G}$.

Let $\gamma>0$.

How does the probability of
$$
\{ \sum_{j \in \mathcal{G}} r_j * 1\{W_j>d_j\}>\gamma\}
$$
vary with $N:=|\mathcal{G}|$ if we fix $\gamma$, $R=r_1+r_2+...+r_k$ and $d_1,...,d_k$? I have asked a similar question here [Studying the probability of an event](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133329/studying-the-probability-of-an-event), but now I need to manage this thing with a continuous distribution unfortunately.

Comment: I don't get quite well the question. Just a comment that maybe simplify a bit the setting. It seems to me that that without of generality you can assume that $a=0$ and $b=1$ (or if you prefer you can fix $a=1$ or $b=2$ or what ever of your favorite values). My point is that you can start by 'deleting' non relevant variable of your problem to make it more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using properties of [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)), you can find the solution:

what is the probability of $(w_j>d_j)$?

$$P(w_j>d_j)=\frac{b-d_j}{b-a}$$

Now

$$P(\Sigma r_k 1(w_k>d_k)\geq \gamma)=P(\Sigma r_k \frac{b-d_k}{b-a}  u_k\geq \gamma)$$

when $u_k\in [0,1]$ with uniform distribution.

According to inverse of characteristic function,

$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-itx}\varphi(t) dt$$

In this case, $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of weighted sum of uniformly distributed numbers probabilities:

$$\varphi(t)=\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^N (e^{i r_k \frac{b-d_j}{b-a}t}-1)}{\Pi_{k=1}^Nr_k \frac{b-d_k}{b-a}(it)^N}$$

$$f(x)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-itx}\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^N (e^{i r_k \frac{b-d_j}{b-a}t}-1)}{\Pi_{k=1}^Nr_k \frac{b-d_k}{b-a}(it)^N} dt$$

$$P(\Sigma r_k 1(w_k>d_k)\geq \gamma)=\int_{\gamma}^\infty f(x)dx=\frac1{2\pi} \int_{\gamma}^\infty \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-itx}\frac{\Pi_{k=1}^N (e^{i r_k \frac{b-d_j}{b-a}t}-1)}{\Pi_{k=1}^Nr_k \frac{b-d_k}{b-a}(it)^N} dtdx$$